# Plotting stacked bar chart using google charts

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I have this script which should plot stacked google chart from the json data kept at wwwroot -

```
     <html>
<head>
    <title>DevOps Monitoring Application</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/256/plex-icon.png" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        tr > th::first-line {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {
            packages: ["corechart"]
        }).then(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/TestExecutionResult.json",
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (jsonData) {

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Test case execution time');

                $.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
                    data.addRow([key, parseInt(value)]);
                });


                var options = {
                    title: 'DevOps Monitoring Chart',
                    isStacked: true,
                    legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 3, textStyle: { fontSize: 6 } },
                    bar: { groupWidth: "50%" },
                    hAxis: {
                        format: 'HH:mm', gridlines: { count: 50 },
                        slantedText: false, slantedTextAngle: 45, textStyle: { fontSize: 11 }
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Total execution time (seconds)',
                        viewWindow: {
                            max: 30,
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('barchart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR, status, errorThrown)
                // add fail callback
                alert('error: ' + errorThrown);
            });
        });
    </script>

   
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <u><a href="https://example/TestExecutionResultPOD1.zip">Logs</a></u>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <u><a id="Release link">Release Link</a></u>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h id="TestLogFileName">
                            Last 5 Results: <select>
                                <option value="--Select Results--">--Select Results--</option>
                                <option value="Test Run at 9:30am">Test Run at 9:30am</option>
                                <option value="Test Run at 9:00am">Test Run at 9:00am</option>
                                <option value="Test Run at 8:30am">Test Run at 8:30am</option>
                                <option value="Test Run at 8:00am">Test Run at 8:00am</option>
                                <option value="Test Run at 7:30am">Test Run at 7:30am</option>
                            </select>
                        </h>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <div id="LastSuccessfulRun" style="font-size:12px;color:green;margin-top: -15px;margin-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 5px;">Last successful run at: 06-03-2022 09:43:31</div>
                <div id="barchart" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px"></div>
            </td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The json file has following data -

```
   {"NewAdvisorAccountCreation":4,"AccountActivation":13,"OrganizationCreationForAdvisor":31,"AddingWidgetForDashboard":0}
```

But its plotting a simple column chart and not a stacked column chart. How do I populate a single column chart with these 4 values stacked over one another in different colors.
The legend should have the 4 json keys plotting the 4 json values.
Any help, pointers indicators would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens when you load this url `http://localhost/TestExecutionResult.json` in the browser? It seems that your ajax call to fetch the json is failing

Comment: I see json data as depicted above

Comment: add `console.log(jqXHR, status, errorThrown)` before your alert to see the error. Or check your network tab to see what wrong with that http request

Comment: I've seen, i'm getting CORS error but when i click on json data, it shows values

Comment: @Diogo Gomes:
I have resolved CORS issue now, can you check the question again, i've updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating one row for each "column".

I think this code will work for you:

```
var columns = ['Test Execution'], row = ["test execution X"];

$.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
    columns.push(key);
    row.push(value);
});

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    columns,
    row,
]);
```

Your json is the data for a single row.
So we label that row (on my example "test execution X") and loop over the json to add columns and values for each entry on that json.